# Equivalent to storing cookie on Mobile application without browser

Tags: android, ios, mobile, tornado

I'd like to know the mechanism for storing a secret key on a mobile application for session authentication. I have a Tornado webserver that will use third party external services to authenticate users with E.g. Facebook or Google. I'm familiar with storing cookies using the `set_secure_cookie` when using a browser. However what if a mobile application is now connecting and doing the authentication. What mechanism would I use to store a **secret** like a secure cookie for future session authentication? The below shows the code for validating a user:

```
class GoogleOAuth2LoginHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler,
                               tornado.auth.GoogleOAuth2Mixin):
    async def get(self):
        if self.get_argument('code', False):
            user = await self.get_authenticated_user(
                redirect_uri='http://your.site.com/auth/google',
                code=self.get_argument('code'))
            # Save the user with e.g. set_secure_cookie
        else:
            await self.authorize_redirect(
                redirect_uri='http://your.site.com/auth/google',
                client_id=self.settings['google_oauth']['key'],
                scope=['profile', 'email'],
                response_type='code',
                extra_params={'approval_prompt': 'auto'})
```

How would this be modified for a mobile application that doesn't rely on a browser and cookie support?

Comment: Why not use the keychain?

Comment: Hi Mobile Ben can you please link me to some documentation around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS, there is an API in the NSHTTPCookie class where you can save the entire http response string.
The code will be something like below to create a cookie.

```
if let requestUrl = url {
            let httpCookies = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: response.allHeaderFields as! [String : String], for: requestUrl)
        }
```

Then you can save the cookie,

```
HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookies(httpCookie, for: url, mainDocumentURL: url)
```

You can also access this cookie and set it to the WebView if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it is what you are looking for but you could you use the SharedPreferences system, it is very simple and allows to save locally key-pair values to store any useful information.

With Android you can use the [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) or the [EncryptedSharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences) to add an extra security layer…

And with iOS you have roughly the same mechanism called [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults) that allows as well to store key-pair values, allowing also extra security layers.

Comment: hi JBA, thanks for that however in the code at the point where i save the cookie I.e.  # Save the user with e.g. set_secure_cookie how can i securely push the key from the server to the client for storage?

Comment: NSUserDefaults is not secure.